# How to merge two dataframe with some same column name in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, plotly

is there a way i can combine two dataframes which has some column name same but rest different?
For example:

```
df1:
Name age sex
Mary 32  F
Susan 43 f
Robert 34 M

df2:
age sex eyecolor
22  M   Blue
18  M   Brown
33  F   Black
```

is there a way i can combine these two dataframes with any missing value as 0?
expected output:

```
Name    age sex eyecolor
Mary    32   F   0
Susan   43   f   0
Robert  34   M   0
  0     22   M   Blue
  0     18   M   Brown
  0     33   F   Black
```

Comment: Have you tried pd concat with outer join?

Comment: @MTALY Yes i tried it, i am not getting the required output with missing values  replaced as 0, so I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` with `fillna` to replace **NaN values** with **0**

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).fillna(0)
```

Gives:

```
     Name age sex eyecolor
0    Mary  32   F        0
1   Susan  43   f        0
2  Robert  34   M        0
0       0  22   M     Blue
1       0  18   M    Brown
2       0  33   F    Black
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['age', 'sex'], how='outer').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
     Name  age sex eyecolor
0    Mary   32   F        0
1   Susan   43   f        0
2  Robert   34   M        0
3       0   22   M     Blue
4       0   18   M    Brown
5       0   33   F    Black
```